# Would erase content and settings affect phone number?

Tags: iphone, ios

I just want to know, I just want to do it safely. My phone always said it's almost full storage but I did delete all my text messages, pictures, apps, etc. I tried everything but it always said the same thing. So I don't know if I erase the content and setting will help me erase some parts in my iPhone 4s. I'm trying to make sure.

Comment: @Buscar *Content* and Settings is what is being deleted with the "Content and Settings" option, and 'content' includes all media on the device.

Answer (score 6):

No, your phone number will not be affected.

Comment: What about phone services, would it be affect.

Comment: @P.ng No, they should not be affected. Any carrier updates will be downloaded automatically when the phone reboots after setting up the SIM card.

Comment: So if I click erase content and settings, when I finish setting the phone, it will come back to normal as always am I right. It's my first time doing this; on July 4th, when I turn off my phone until I turn on my phone to check something until I saw all my apps has been disappear. I don't know. This never happen to me before.- grgarside

Comment: @P.ng Back to 'normal', yes, but obviously without your content (unless you restore from backup) and all settings will be reset to factory default.

Comment: Have u tried it before on your phone. It's my first time of doing this.

Comment: @P.ng Yes, I've done this many times!

Comment: Alright. But where's the content that u were talking about in the iPhone.

Comment: @P.ng Content is basically everything on your phone that you've put there. All your apps and their data, plus all your photos and videos, contacts, messages, email, etc. All will be erased when the option is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone number will not be affected.

But try to see what is occupying the space with "Settings -> General -> Usage.

Back up via iCloud or iTunes then go ahead and delete stuff.

Look for apps that use a lots of space and delete them "Delete App and Delete App again to confirm.

Your messages can contain a lots of photos send to you that consume space.

If you are unsure if you want to keep some you need to "Manually Find & Save Photo Messages".

Comment: Okay, I'm in settings right now, so do I click general and then go to usage. But I already delete the message but how do u delete some messages in messages (saved).